# Insert SMS in Database in Lollipop

Tags: android

In my app, I need to add some SMS to the Android messages database.

My code is basically the next:

```
    public static boolean addMessage()
     {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(Sms.ADDRESS, "99912345");
            cv.put(Sms.BODY, "Testing message");
            cv.put(Sms.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
            cv.put(Sms.DATE_SENT, System.currentTimeMillis() - 10 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
            cv.put(Sms.READ, 0);
            Uri u = context.getContentResolver().insert(Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, cv);
            return u != null;
     }
```

and I have declared the corresponding permissions in the Manifest:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
> ```

When I execute the function, the insert returns always

> content://sms/inbox/0

and the SMS isn't at the database.
The logcat don't displays anything special.

My OS version is Android 5.0.2

I edit my question...

Deu to isn't possible to use the standard (and possibly unoficial) API to update SMS database in Android versions higher to 19, I wont to add root permissions to my app to update the database manually, using commands like the provided in this article: http://muzso.hu/2013/04/07/changing-android-system-settings-eg.-airplane-mode-radios-via-commandline-on-rooted-phone

If I use this commands, is possible to force the Telephony provider to reload the database after I update it?

Thanks again!

Comment: in +19 just default sms app can work with SMS database

Comment: Agreed. Is your app the default SMS client for the device? As Shayan notes, nobody else has write access: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: Not possible to force the Telephony provider to reload the database after update it via command line (root)?